# How to find the overall Avg grade without adding a new column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tried searching on here for the answer, but it has been a lost cause so far.
I am a student in my first SQL class.

Here is the question.

Provide an alphabetic list of students (student ID and name) who have an overall grade average 
that is a C or lower (less than 80). 
The name should be one column, last name first and sorted on last name then first name.

HERE IS MY CODE.

```
SELECT GRADE.STUDENT_ID,Last_Name || ', '||First_Name AS Student_Name
FROM GRADE,Student
WHERE Student.STUDENT_ID = GRADE.STUDENT_ID 
HAVING AVG(Numeric_Grade) <= 80
ORDER BY Last_Name,First_Name;
```

I get this error message using the HAVING clause: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function.

I am not sure how to get the avg grade... Any help would be appreciated
Thank you in advance

Comment: If you get an ORA error, first of all search for the reason before asking. http://www.ora-error.com/ This is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should a GROUP BY clause before calling a HAVING or any agregate function

example :

```
SELECT GRADE.STUDENT_ID,Last_Name || ', '||First_Name AS Student_Name
FROM GRADE,Student
WHERE Student.STUDENT_ID = GRADE.STUDENT_ID

--Important
GROUP BY Student.STUDENT_ID

HAVING AVG(Numeric_Grade) <= 80
ORDER BY Last_Name,First_Name;
```

Then you would be able to add a call to AVG in your SELECT clause for exemple `AVG(Numeric_Grade) as AverageGrade`. You might as well need to add more columns to your GROUP BY clause in order to be able to access them in the SELECT clause.